# Plotly returning evenly spaced piecharts

Tags: python, plotly, pie-chart, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a pie chart using plotly, but it seems it is always retuning even plots regardless of values provided

```
import plotly.express as px
df_africa['CompFreq'].value_counts().tolist() # check for the particular order the labels should be in 

sizes = df_africa['CompFreq'].value_counts().tolist()

labels = ['Monthly', 'Yearly', 'Weekly']
# Plot

fig = px.pie(sizes, names=labels, color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu)
fig.show()
```

The sizes variable contains the list below

```
[923, 168, 40]
```

[image: Plot returned from code above]

Answer (score 0):

For `plotly.express`, the first argument needs to be a DataFrame, dictionary, or array-like. This is explained in the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/#passing-dictionaries-or-arraylikes-as-the-dataframe-argument).

However, for your use case, I think it would be simplest to just directly pass your list of sector sizes to the `values` parameter:

```
fig = px.pie(names=labels, values=sizes, color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.RdBu)
```

[image]